# Target an attribute within HTML tags with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex, atom-editor

I'm looking for a regex expression which targets any HTML attribute named `attrName` so that I can replace it with `attr` but within `<Highlight></Highlight>` tags only.

An example of a block I would be targeting is:

```
<Highlight attrName="html">
 {'
   <div attrName="input action">
   \n\t<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search..."/>
   \n\t<a attrName="button outlined">Search</a>
   \n</div>
 '}
</Highlight>
```

So far I just came up with the regex `<Highlight\s*(attrName)\s*` but it just targets `<Highlight attrName`

Comment: Parse the HTML to DOM elements, don't use a regular expression.

Comment: Why, oh why with regex? [It never stops](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5459839).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I'm just using the find & replace regex feature within my code editor

Comment: What is this `{'` syntax? Are you using some templating library?

Comment: It's used here to escape HTML entities in JSX, as I'm using ReactJS

Comment: *find & replace regex feature within my code editor*  - what is the code editor?

Comment: Its [Atom](http://atom.io)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I currently have `<Highlight[^>]*>(.|\n)*?</Highlight>` which selects the whole block. Is there a way to just select instances of `attrName`  within the block using this expression?

Comment: If the S&R feature does not let you specify the replacement inside a block- no.

Comment: I think this will do it `(?!\<Highlight)attrName(?!.*\<\/Highlight\>)`

Comment: Hmm Titus, that selected all `attrName`s in the code instead of only within the `Highlight` blocks

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, all the feature does within Atom is search and select a string or a regex expression. From there, you can replace any selection with another string as specified.

Comment: If you want to do this with regex, you need powerful regex flavor such as PCRE or .NET regex. Why not use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which supports PCRE. You can use a pattern [like this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hB9mI9/1) (still inefficient).

Comment: @bobblebubble that worked perfectly, thank you kind sir. I literally just copied my code straight into the demo ha. No idea regex had such different flavors.  If you'd like to post it as an answer i'll happily accept it!

Comment: @Sanction You're welcome! glad it helps (: Yes, there are many dfferent regex flavors. Most powerful probably .NET regex and PCRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that parsing such code by regex is not always a good idea, you'd probably need a more powerful regex flavor than provided by the Atom-editor. How about [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) which supports PCRE.

Here you can use the [`\G` anchor to chain matches](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) from start or a certain point.

```
(?s)(?:<Hi[^>]*>|\G(?!^))(?:(?!</Hi).)*?\KattrName
```

- The `(?s)` [flag](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) is to make the dot also match newlines.
- `(?:<Hi[^>]*>|\G(?!^))` the first part inside the [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group) is to set where the match begins. Without `(?!^)` negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `\G` would also match the beginning of the string.
- `(?:(?!</Hi).)*?`  the second part to match any amount of characters while not skipping `</Hi` by use of a negative lookahead and [reset the match by use of `\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) before `attrName`.

[Here is the demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hB9mI9/1)

Comment: Thanks again, also great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

This will find the attribute: `(?<=<[^<]+)attrName(?=\s*=[^>]+>)`

This will find HTML tags in which the attribute occurs: `<[^<]+attrName\s*=[^>]+>`